# SQL How to get a value from group by in a prior month to use in current group by?

Tags: sql

How do you get the count of leads this year and the count of leads for last year on the same row.  The query I need is more complicated, however this is the first step.

Output

```
Year,Count,Last Year Count
2016,55,88
2017,77,55
2018,83,77
```

```
SELECT L1.Year, count(L1.LeadId), count(Lead_Last_Year.Lead_count) from Leads
???
Group by Year
```

Thank You

Comment: What RDBMs are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to left join the grouping subqueries.

```
SELECT x.year,
       x.count,
       y.count last_year_count
       FROM (SELECT l1.year,
                    count(l1.leadid) count
                    FROM leads l1
                    GROUP BY l1.year) x
            LEFT JOIN (SELECT l1.year,
                              count(l1.leadid) count
                              FROM leads l1
                              GROUP BY l1.year) y
                      ON y.year = x.year - 1;
```

If your DBMS supports CTEs you can also use a CTE instead of the recurring subquery.

```
WITH cte
AS
(
SELECT l1.year,
       count(l1.leadid) count
       FROM leads l1
       GROUP BY l1.year
)
SELECT x.year,
       x.count,
       y.count last_year_count
       FROM cte x
            LEFT JOIN cte y
                      ON y.year = x.year - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a join on the result from the first select.  So you could do:

```
SELECT 
   L1.Year,
   count(L1.LeadId), 
   count(L2.LeadId) 
FROM Leads L1
LEFT JOIN Leads L2 on L1.Year = L2.Year+1
Group by Year
```

Comment: You might want to change it to a LEFT join so that first row has null instead of getting removed.

Comment: Thanks Sean, unfortunately that is what I was trying and it was not working.  Sticky Bit's answer worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ISO/ANSI standard `LAG()` function:

```
SELECT l.Year, count(*),
       LAG(COUNT(*)) OVER (ORDER BY l.YEAR) as prev_year
FROM Leads l
GROUP BY l.Year;
```

This should have the best performance compared to other methods.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, this looks great. Unfortunately, Zoho Reports Sql does not support this.  I will make a note of it when using other SQL programs.